# Using MySQL Data as datasource for Google Maps Demographics

Tags: mysql, google-maps

Any resources on how to get started with using Google maps demographics layer with mysql data?
I'm currently going through this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics

And it seems like the data is coming from Nielsen. How do I use data coming from mysql database for the demographics layer?

For example I have this data:

```
var demo_data = [['forest', 'ABC Forest', lat , lng], 
                 ['mountain', 'Mt. Everest', lat, lng], 
                 ['forest', 'DEF Forest', lat, lng]];
```

Then maybe I'll just loop through it to determine which one is forest and which one is mountain then apply the styling used in demographics to treat all the areas with forest/mountains as one unit.

Any links that will give me some clues on how to do this will definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demographics layer is displayed as rendered tiles (with the ability to get specific attributes on click events).

Can you be more clear what you mean by "data coming from mysql database"?  Are you suggesting you have your own demographic data you want to render as tiles, or that you have different data you'd like to overlay on top of the demographic layer provided by the Google Maps API, or something else?

Comment: It sounds like you have some point locations (for example mountains), and you want to apply demographic styling to the points?  I think I am not understanding correctly .. can you be more clear how demographics apply to your mountains, and what exactly you're trying to accomplish?